# Android Studio fails to find Cocopods installation after upgrade to Bumblebee on Mac M1

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

I had an upgrade on Android Studio from Arctic Fox to Bumblebee v2021.1.1 on Mac M1 and surprisingly iOS version of Flutter app stopped working. It says

> Cocoapods not installed.skipping pod install
> However, I can locate cocoapods and its components installed

```
gem list --local | grep cocoapods
```

I can run the iOS project from Xcode without any issues, and looks like linking of cocoapods is messed up on Android upgrade. Looking for some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a issue of flutter integration with new update of android studio
Here you can find more about this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/97251

for now there are two solutions:

1. Open android studio using command line, run below command in terminal -

   `open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app`
2. Add missing flag to android studio, run below command in terminal -

   `chmod +x /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/printenv`

Comment: Solution looks viable, but it brings me back to same stage every time I update flutter channel.